# Install MySql With default Configure automatically with install4j on Linux

Tags: linux, install4j

I building a installer for my application and want to install mysql With default Configure on user PC automatically. how to install mysql automatically without be user set Configure(example password,user,instance)? On linux
1.How i install MySQL on Linux with install4j ?
2.How to run .sh file in install4j?

Answer (score 0):

You can run any third party installer with a "Run executable or batch file" action.

The mysql installer has a quiet mode that can be invoked like this:

```
msiexec /i "path to msi file" /qn INSTALLDIR="mysql installation dir"
```

For the "Run executable or batch file", you have to set the "Executable" property to

```
${installer:sys.system32Dir}\msiexec
```

and the "Arguments" property (in the "..." editor) to

```
${installer:sys.installationDir}\mysql.msi
/qn
INSTALLDIR=${installer:sys.programGroupDir}\mysql
```

If you add the mysql msi file to the distribution tree at the top level and it's named 'mysql.msi' and if you want to install it to `%PROGRAMFILES%\mysql`.

Configuring the instance can be done with the `MysqlInstanceConfig.exe` helper, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.html for more information.